# Integration of Hadoop and Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr, bigdata

According to my research, I can integrate hadoop and solr. I have downloaded and install both of them. But couldn't integrate them with each other. And also I couldn't find a proper tutorial for this purpose.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.02, Apache Hadoop 2.6.0 and Solr 5.2.1.

How can I integrate Hadoop and Solr on my machine?

Note: I installed hadoop as Single Node. Also I am very beginner about this concepts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Solr with hadoop in two ways

1. document based
2. using lily indexers With Hbase

so if you want to use a document that present in HDFS to be indexed by SOLR.
you need to follow following steps:
Step A.

```
solrctl --zk zookeeper_server:port/solr --solr solr-server:port/solr instancedir --generate <path of collection>/collection_name
```

edit /collection_name/conf/schema.xml with your attributes that present in Data to be indexed

```
solrctl --zk zookeeper_server:port/solr --solr solr-server:port/solr instancedir --create <collection_name> <path of collection>/collection_name
solrctl --zk zookeeper_server:port/solr --solr solr-server:port/solr  collection --create <collection_name> -s <num_of_solr_shard> -r <num_of_solr_replication>
```

you can any number to  ,  but

*  <= number of solr nodes in cluster
eg If you have 7 nodes , you can have 3,2 or 2,3 as per need.

so for your case it would be 1 & 1.

Step B.
once collection is been created , Data can be indexed by following command

```
curl http://solr-server:port/solr/<collection_name>/update/csv --data-binary @<path_of_data_file_in_linux> -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

If you want to index Hbase Data follow Step A. to create Solr Collection, & Then use Lily Indexer(key value indexer) to create indexer on hbase , after that that data can be seen on SOLR as XML or JSON.

Comment: thanks for you advise. I have two questions,
1. I couldn't find solrctl, where this locate
2. how can I learn zookeeper address and port

Comment: In standard installation, solrctl can be found at /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.36/bin/solrctl

Comment: You can type hbase zkcli , & you will see
zk: XXXXXXXX:2181(CONNECTED) 0]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read about Cloudera Search (http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-search/v1-latest/Cloudera-Search-User-Guide/csug_introducing.html)

This is basically an open source project by cloudera integrating Hadoop and Solr.